# What the best way to redirect a domain from Crystone to another hosted site?

Tags: redirect, dns, cname, google-index

We have registered a domain at Crystone and the site is since previously hosted at appharbor. For the start I've setup the domain to redirect using frame forwarding but I've started to run into problems when using google index. Google want me to prove that the site is mine and there is several methods for proving this. Either I can place a file at the root or enter some tags in the index file but since when using frame forwarding the primary index file is encapsulated in a frame both these methods fails.

At Crystone I can't really access the frame that forwards the domain so I can't handle this page. I know that frame forwarding isn't the best to use but I really want to avoid that the visitors to the site doesn't have to see the hosted address.

Can/should I use CName records for the redirect? I cannot use an A records since I don't know the ip-adress to appharbor and my site.

Comment: have you found answer of your question? My personal experience is that crystone is a worthless provider, I highly recommend everybody not to use their service.

Comment: I found out that it really isn't a good practice to use frame-forwarding if you want to be found by google and other search sites. I haven't found that Crystone are bad, just that you couldn't make changes in this way. Not many other providers that accepts this either.